# How to read efficiently a huge text file in java and split its content to sort it?

Tags: java, file, sorting

I have the following structure of a textfile (around 360741 KB):

```
123123123123,123123123,1,123123,123123,NAME1,LASTNAME1,LASTNAME2
```

Since I need to sort the file by name, I'm trying to to place it in a LinkedList to make it easier for me to sort it by an algorithm like Merge-Sort or Quicksort.

The issue I have is that it takes too long to Split every line and place it in a LinkedList.

Could you guys suggest me alternative for doing this in a more time-efficient way?

What I'm doing:

```
   try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\MyDirectory\\File.txt"));
        String str;
        LinkedList<Persona> li = new LinkedList();
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(str);
            String[] array = str.split(",");

             //Take the values from the array to create an instance of the class and place it in the LinkedList.
            li.add(new Persona(array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4],array[5],array[6],array[7]));
            //System.out.println(str);
        }
        System.out.println("fin");
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File Read Error");
    }

}
```

Comment: Side note - Don't do this `System.out.println("File Read Error");` in a catch. Do `e.printStackTrace()` also or instead.

Comment: Your solution will take more time since I have to Split it to sort it.

Comment: Define "too long." Reading in 350MB isn't going to be instantaneous. If you're not concerned about implementing the sorting algorithm and your entires are unique, I would use a different data structure that would sort on insert to save a lot of time. (`TreeSet` or something like that).

Comment: If you use split(String regex, int limit) with the limit that you want ... and then later on split the remaining does that help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LinkedList is not particularly efficient in terms of memory and no good for the built in sort algorythims.  I suggest you load each line into an Array List and split it only by the name (not each field as you don't need to break those up)

You can sort an ArrayList with Collections.sort and a custom comparator.

Note: you can expect 352 MB of text to use at least 1 GB of memory and I would suggest giving it 2-4 GB to improve performance.

Comment: Well, actually I MUST implement the sorting algorithm so I won't be using Collections.sort.

Comment: @user2327884 Why MUST you implement the sorting algorithm?

Comment: Because it's part of a homework in which I have to implement a concurrent sorting algorithm and a sequential sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This would take 5 different steps:

1) Split the file into sections (of course you know this, maybe 10 MB chunks). Something manageable by your seemingly small ram capacity.

2) Sort each chunk respectively. Save to its own file (this is for easy management)

3) Merge each of the sorted lists into seperate files by A-Z letters as files names (or however you want depending on how many A's compare to Z's i.e  A1.txt A2.txt A3.txt ...etc)

4) Sort the Merged files by groups in separate larger files. (All the A's then the B's ... etc)

5) Merge the files into one large file (if you wish) Order accordingly

Note: This is also known as `External Sort`. And you shouldn't be using linkedlists. Try something like vectors or some already built sorting functions.